# Empty typeorm_metadata table

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mariadb, typeorm

I have an empty typeorm_metadata table. While running generate migration command: `npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:generate migrationTest -d ./src/data-source.ts`

I get this error:

```
query: SELECT `t`.*, `v`.`check_option` FROM `typeorm_metadata` `t` INNER JOIN `information_schema`.`views` `v` ON `v`.`table_schema` = `t`.`schema` AND `v`.`table_name` = `t`.`name` WHERE `t`.`type` = 'VIEW' AND ((`t`.`schema` = ‘mainDB’ AND `t`.`name` = 'video_count_view') OR (`t`.`schema` = 'mainDB' AND `t`.`name` = 'view_application'))
Error during migration generation:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

> Node version: v18.18.0
> ExpressJs : 4.18.2
> Ts version : 4.9.5
> Typeorm : 0.3.17
> MariaDB

Error during migration generation:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

But while running this query directly it’s not showing any error just empty response.

```
Docker
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.35+desktop.5
 Version:           24.0.7
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.10
 Git commit:        afdd53b
 Built:             Thu Oct 26 09:04:20 2023
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           desktop-linux

Server: Docker Desktop 4.26.1 (131620)
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.7
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.10
  Git commit:       311b9ff
  Built:            Thu Oct 26 09:08:15 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.25
  GitCommit:        d8f198a4ed8892c764191ef7b3b06d8a2eeb5c7f
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.10
  GitCommit:        v1.1.10-0-g18a0cb0
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```